# Can i count bars in pine script and after x bars put a trade not on first bar? PINE SCRIPT

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

this startegy is based on ssl channel and some other indicators like pivot points and ema. When line above change to green, it place long order and when it turns red it exit but i want to add a filter to this changes bcs sometimes this above line change colors bar after a bar and it turns winning trades into lossing trades becouse of fees. Thanks for any advise and dont judge me for this code, im newbie :P

there is the code:

```
//@version=5
strategy("channel", overlay=true, pyramiding=0)


//ema
leng = input.int(200, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input.int(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)
out = ta.ema(src, leng)
plot(out, title="EMA", color=color.blue, offset=offset)

//channel
period=input(title="Period", defval=10)
len=input(title="Period", defval=10)
smaHigh=ta.sma(high, len)
smaLow=ta.sma(low, len)
Hlv = float(na)
Hlv := close > smaHigh ? 1 : close < smaLow ? -1 : Hlv[1]
sslDown = Hlv < 0 ? smaHigh: smaLow
sslUp   = Hlv < 0 ? smaLow : smaHigh

plot(sslDown, linewidth=2, color=color.red)
plot(sslUp, linewidth=2, color=color.lime)

//pivot
gr="LENGTH LEFT / RIGHT"
leftLenH = input.int(title="Pivot High", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot High",group=gr)
rightLenH = input.int(title="/", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot High",group=gr)
colorH = input(title="", defval=#E3EFFD, inline="Pivot High",group=gr)

leftLenL = input.int(title="Pivot Low", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot Low", group=gr)
rightLenL = input.int(title="/", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot Low",group=gr)
colorL = input(title="", defval=#E3EFFD, inline="Pivot Low",group=gr)

ph = ta.pivothigh(leftLenH, rightLenH)
pl = ta.pivotlow(leftLenL, rightLenL)

drawLabel(_offset, _pivot, _style, _color) =>
    if not na(_pivot)
        label.new(bar_index[_offset], _pivot, str.tostring(_pivot, format.mintick), style=_style, color=_color, textcolor=#131722)

drawLabel(rightLenH, ph, label.style_label_down, colorH)
drawLabel(rightLenL, pl, label.style_label_up, colorL)

//long contition
L1 = if (close and open and high and low  > out)
    true
else
    false 
L2 = if (sslDown < sslUp)
    true
else
    false
//L3 = if (sslUp > out)
//    true
//else
//    false
L = if (L2 and L1 == true)
    true
else
    false

if (L == true)
    strategy.entry("el", strategy.long)
plotshape(sslDown < sslUp, location=location.abovebar, style=shape.arrowup,   color=color.green)
exitL = if (sslDown > sslUp)
    true
else
    false
if (exitL == true)
    strategy.close(id="el")
//short contition 
S1 = if (close and open and high and low  < out)
    true
else
    false 
S2 = if (sslDown > sslUp)
    true
else
    false
S = if (S2 and S1 == true)
    true
else
    false
if (S == true)
    strategy.entry("es", strategy.short)
plotshape(sslDown > sslUp, location=location.belowbar, style=shape.arrowup,   color=color.red)
exitS = if (sslDown < sslUp)
    true
else
    false
if (exitS == true)
    strategy.close(id="es")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have added to two input variables. First is bars to be skipped after long condition is met and Second is bars to be skipped after short condition is met. Default is 2. This means your long or short order will be placed 2 bars after your long or short conditions are met and not immediately.

Play with these setting and Enjoy...Hope I have given you a solution.

```html
    //@version=5
strategy("channel", overlay=true, pyramiding=0)


//ema
leng = input.int(200, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, title="Source")
offset = input.int(title="Offset", defval=0, minval=-500, maxval=500)

LongbarOffset = input.int(title = "Bars to skip from long condition",defval=2)
ShortbarOffset = input.int(title = "Bars to skip from Short condition",defval=2)

out = ta.ema(src, leng)
plot(out, title="EMA", color=color.blue, offset=offset)

//channel
period=input(title="Period", defval=10)
len=input(title="Period", defval=10)
smaHigh=ta.sma(high, len)
smaLow=ta.sma(low, len)
Hlv = float(na)
Hlv := close > smaHigh ? 1 : close < smaLow ? -1 : Hlv[1]
sslDown = Hlv < 0 ? smaHigh: smaLow
sslUp   = Hlv < 0 ? smaLow : smaHigh

plot(sslDown, linewidth=2, color=color.red)
plot(sslUp, linewidth=2, color=color.lime)

//pivot
gr="LENGTH LEFT / RIGHT"
leftLenH = input.int(title="Pivot High", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot High",group=gr)
rightLenH = input.int(title="/", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot High",group=gr)
colorH = input(title="", defval=#E3EFFD, inline="Pivot High",group=gr)

leftLenL = input.int(title="Pivot Low", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot Low", group=gr)
rightLenL = input.int(title="/", defval=10, minval=1, inline="Pivot Low",group=gr)
colorL = input(title="", defval=#E3EFFD, inline="Pivot Low",group=gr)

ph = ta.pivothigh(leftLenH, rightLenH)
pl = ta.pivotlow(leftLenL, rightLenL)

drawLabel(_offset, _pivot, _style, _color) =>
    if not na(_pivot)
        label.new(bar_index[_offset], _pivot, str.tostring(_pivot, format.mintick), style=_style, color=_color, textcolor=#131722)

drawLabel(rightLenH, ph, label.style_label_down, colorH)
drawLabel(rightLenL, pl, label.style_label_up, colorL)

var int bCount = 0
//long contition
L1 = if (close and open and high and low  > out)
    true
else
    false 
L2 = if (sslDown < sslUp)
    true
else
    false
//L3 = if (sslUp > out)
//    true
//else
//    false
L = if (L2 and L1 == true)
    true
    bCount := bar_index
else
    false

b = ta.barssince(L==true)
Longbcount = na(b)? 1 : b


if (Longbcount == LongbarOffset)
    strategy.entry("el", strategy.long)
plotshape(sslDown < sslUp, location=location.abovebar, style=shape.arrowup,   color=color.green)

exitL = if (sslDown > sslUp)
    true
else
    false
if (exitL == true)
    strategy.close(id="el")
//short contition 
S1 = if (close and open and high and low  < out)
    true
else
    false 
S2 = if (sslDown > sslUp)
    true
else
    false
S = if (S2 and S1 == true)
    true
else
    false

c = ta.barssince(S==true)
Shortbcount = na(c)? 1 : c


if (Shortbcount == ShortbarOffset)
    strategy.entry("es", strategy.short)
plotshape(sslDown > sslUp, location=location.belowbar, style=shape.arrowup,   color=color.red)
exitS = if (sslDown < sslUp)
    true
else
    false
if (exitS == true)
    strategy.close(id="es")
```